# sql: selecting a value in an attributes table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with the following schema:

- thing

  - id
  - id_thing_type
- thing_attribute

  - id
  - name
  - id_thing_type
- thing_attribute_value

  - id_thing_attribute
  - value_date
- Thing has many Thing_Attributes joined on `thing.id_thing_type = thing_attribute.id_thing_type`
- Thing_Attributes have one Thing_Attribute_Value joined on `thing_attribute.id = thing_attribute_value.id_thing_attribute`

I am trying to write a query that will return the value of a specific attribute (with a certain `name`) for a specific thing record (with a certain `id`). `thing.id` represents a unique row.

Said another way, `thing_attribute` and `thing` both have an `id_thing_type`.  These tables need to be joined on `id_thing_type` = `id_thing_type`.   Think of this as each type of `thing` has its own unique set of `thing_attributes`.  The task is to find the value of a specific attribute of a specific thing.

This is what I have so far, however it returns many rows:

```
SELECT t.id, tav.value_date
FROM thing_attribute_value tav
JOIN thing_attribute ta
    ON tav.id_node_attribute = ta.id
JOIN thing t
    ON ta.id_thing_type = t.id_thing_type
WHERE ta.name = 'Birth Date'
AND t.id = '123'
```

Here is an example result.  As you can see, many rows are returned, all with the same id for `thing`, but with different dates.

```
123,2015-12-02
123,2014-11-02
123,2013-07-11
123,2014-03-12
etc....
```

Comment: What's your desired output and what does the data look like?

Comment: It all depend on what you want to see.  I don't know what your data should look like.  Also in your query, where do you get `n.id` from?  I don't see any table alias `n`.

Comment: @eric `n.id` should have been `t.id`.  I will work on some sample data.

Comment: @MrJF The desired output is the value of the specific `thing_attribute` (where `thing_attribute.name = 'Birth Date'`) for a specific `thing` (where `thing.id = '123'`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  DBMS should not be relevant here.  Generic SQL answer should suffice.  If it matters, assume MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

So, as discussed in the comments to my original answer:

Thing has a Thing_Type_Id Column.
And Thing_Attribute has a Thing_Type_Id Column.
For which there is a 1::1 relationship.

Thing_Attribute has a Thing_Attribute_Value_Id column.
And Thing_Attribute_Value has an Id column.
For which there is a 1::Many relationship.

This is what is causing your query to fail.  The error is actually in your data relationships, not the query.

Let's try to piece this together:

Thing 
- needs a unique id
- can have any number of other columns
- will have many attributes, but this column will not be in this table

Thing_Attributes
- needs a unique id
- needs a Thing id (fk to Thing)
- needs a Type id (fk to Thing_Attribute_Type)
- needs a Value

Thing_Attribute_Value - can go away - Replace it with a lookup for Type

Thing_Attribute_Type
- needs unique id
- needs Value

With this relational structure you can have many Attributes for each Thing
You use an id field for Attribute Type so you are not repeating a strings.
Use a lookup that gets an Attribute_Type value based on the Id.

This is an overhaul to your current relationship model, but with your current one you cannot isolate a given attribute value to a given Thing, which I think was at least one of the goals in building your Thing objects.

Comment: Your suggestion is not quite right.  `thing_attribute` and `thing` both have an `id_thing_type`.  These tables need to be joined on `id_thing_type` = `id_thing_type`.   Think of this as each type of `thing` has its own unique set of `thing_attributes`.  The task is to find the value of a specific attribute of specify thing.

Comment: can you do a simple select on Thing_Attribute where id_thing_type = id_thing_type from your example Thing and tell me how many results you get?

Comment: there are 8 results.  this makes sense  - the `Thing` matching `id = 123` has  8 attributes.  You may have meant however to exclude the `where` clauses.  If this is the case there are 11,733 records.  This would be all of the attributes of all of the things.  If I include both `where` clauses but remove the join to the `thing_attribute_value` table  then I get just one record - the `birth_date` attribute of the `thing` record with an ID of 123.  Now it is just a question of joining to `thing_attribute_value` while still just returning one row.

Comment: Id_Thing_Attribute is not unique in the Thing_Attribute_Value table is it?  Do a SELECT COUNT(*) from Thing_Attribute_Value where Id_Thing_Attribute = result from your query where you removed that join.  I bet you get same number of results as you get from original query in the question.

Comment: you are correct.  `id_thing_attribute` is not unique in `thing_attribute_value` table.  This makes sense in the system I am working in. Lots of `things` of a particular type have the same set of attributes.  So then the answer to this lies in how to exclude the additional rows that are being returned from `thing_attribute_value`.  Any thoughts on that??

Comment: So now I am looking using a nested select to find the id of the thing_attribute and using that in the where clause that for a select on the thing_attribute_value.  Either that or I need to use a different type of join, like perhaps a right join or right outer join.

Comment: I have edited my answer text.  It is not the answer you will want to hear, but it is the one that will fix your data relational model and save you many headaches in the long term.

Comment: Thank you.  This is not schema that I have control over, so changes to the models may or may not be possible,  That said, I can solve the query using a select as the right side of the where clause.